# How to configure jOOQ with Gradle, Testcontainers and Flyway?

Tags: java, gradle, jooq, flyway

I need example of configuration gradle build file for jOOQ with Testcontainers and Flyway, in official repository of jOOQ I found only maven example and can't translate it to gradle, I try to convert it myself, but got this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies { 
        // test container
        classpath "org.testcontainers:postgresql:$testContainersVersion"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'nu.studer.jooq' version "$jooqPluginVersion"
    id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "$flywayPluginVersion"
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // spring
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq'

    // postgres
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'

    // jooq
    jooqGenerator "org.postgresql:postgresql:$postgresVersion"

    // flyway
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'

    // tests
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junitVersion"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junitVersion"
    testImplementation "org.testcontainers:testcontainers:$testContainersVersion"
    testImplementation "org.testcontainers:postgresql:$testContainersVersion"
}
var JdbcDatabaseContainer<?> postgres = new PostgreSQLContainerProvider().newInstance("14-alpine")
postgres.start()

flyway {
    url = postgres.jdbcUrl
    user = postgres.username
    password = postgres.password
    schemas = ['public']
    locations = ['classpath:db/migration']
    baselineOnMigrate = true
}
tasks { 
    doLast {
        if (postgres.isRunning) {
            println("STOPPING DATABASE CONTAINER")
            postgres.stop()
        }
    }
}

jooq {
    version = "$jookVersion"  // default (can be omitted)
    edition = JooqEdition.OSS  // default (can be omitted)

    configurations {
        main {  // name of the jOOQ configuration
            generateSchemaSourceOnCompilation = true  // default (can be omitted)

            generationTool {
                logging = org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Logging.WARN
                jdbc {
                    driver = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
                    url = postgres.jdbcUrl
                    user = postgres.username
                    password = postgres.password
                }
                generator {
                    name = 'org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGenerator'
                    database {
                        name = 'org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase'
                        inputSchema = 'public'
                        forcedTypes {
                            forcedType {
                                userType = 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode'
                                includeTypes = '.*'
                                includeExpression = '.*JSON.*'
                                binding = 'dataflow.binding.PostgresJSONBBinding'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    generate {
                        pojosAsKotlinDataClasses = true
                        deprecated = false
                        records = true
                        pojos = true
                        immutablePojos = false
                        fluentSetters = true
                        daos = true
                    }
                    target {
                        packageName = "dataflow.$dataflowPackageName"
                        directory = 'build/generated-src/jooq/main'  // default (can be omitted)
                    }
                    strategy.name = 'org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGeneratorStrategy'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it's create three container instead of one and don't stop them.
P.S. I use Gradle jOOQ [plugin](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin)

Answer (score 5):

I had similar case recently with mysql, gradle, flyway and jooq. Base on examples from gradle-jooq-plugin (https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin/blob/master/example/) I came up with working solution for my case, with minor changes it should also work for yours:

```
import org.testcontainers.containers.MySQLContainer

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.testcontainers:mysql:1.17.3'
        classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.29'
        classpath 'org.flywaydb:flyway-mysql:9.0.1'

    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.flywaydb.flyway' version '9.0.1'
    id 'nu.studer.jooq' version '7.1.1'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    flywayMigration
}

dependencies {
    jooqGenerator('mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.29')
}

task mysqlContainer {
    var instance = new MySQLContainer("mysql:8.0.29")
            .withDatabaseName('example')
    instance.start()
    mysqlContainer.ext.jdbcUrl = instance.getJdbcUrl()
    mysqlContainer.ext.username = instance.getUsername()
    mysqlContainer.ext.password = instance.getPassword()
    mysqlContainer.ext.databaseName = instance.getDatabaseName()
    mysqlContainer.ext.instance = instance
}

flyway {
    locations = ['filesystem:./src/main/resources/db/migration']
    configurations = ['flywayMigration']
    url = mysqlContainer.jdbcUrl
    user = mysqlContainer.username
    password = mysqlContainer.password
}


jooq {
    configurations {
        main {
            generationTool {
                logging = org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Logging.WARN
                jdbc {
                    driver = 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'
                    url = mysqlContainer.jdbcUrl
                    user =mysqlContainer.username
                    password = mysqlContainer.password
                }
                generator {
                    name = 'org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGenerator'
                    database {
                        name = 'org.jooq.meta.mysql.MySQLDatabase'
                        includes = '.*'
                        inputSchema = mysqlContainer.databaseName
                        outputSchemaToDefault = true
                    }
                    target {
                        packageName = 'com.example.jooq'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.named('generateJooq').configure {
    dependsOn tasks.named('mysqlContainer')
    dependsOn tasks.named('flywayMigrate')

    inputs.files(fileTree('src/main/resources/db/migration'))
            .withPropertyName('migrations')
            .withPathSensitivity(PathSensitivity.RELATIVE)

    allInputsDeclared = true
    doLast {
        mysqlContainer.instance.stop()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

We're using the following flow (It's kotlin and contains only the JOOQ resources-related part of the script). The main difference with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73051138/5058989) is that mine spins up a new container once you run only `generateJooq` task. Another one runs a new container in every task.

```
...

val containerInstance: PostgreSQLContainer<Nothing>? = if ("generateJooq" in project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames) {
    PostgreSQLContainer<Nothing>(
        DockerImageName.parse(
            "postgres:14.4-alpine",
        ),
    ).apply {
        withDatabaseName("my-db")
        start()
    }
} else {
    null
}

flyway {
    url = containerInstance?.jdbcUrl
    user = containerInstance?.username
    password = containerInstance?.password
}

jooq {
    version.set("3.17.5") // default (can be omitted)
    edition.set(nu.studer.gradle.jooq.JooqEdition.OSS) // default (can be omitted)

    configurations {
        create("main") { // name of the jOOQ configuration
            generateSchemaSourceOnCompilation.set(false) // default (can be omitted)
            jooqConfiguration.apply {
                logging = Logging.ERROR
                jdbc.apply {
                    driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
                    url = containerInstance?.jdbcUrl
                    user = containerInstance?.username
                    password = containerInstance?.password
                }
                generator.apply {
                    name = "org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGenerator"
                    database.apply {
                        name = "org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase"
                        inputSchema = "public"
                        isIncludeIndexes = false
                        excludes = "flyway.*"
                    }
                    target.apply {
                        packageName = "mypackage"
                        directory = "src/main/java"
                    }
                    strategy.name = "org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGeneratorStrategy"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// This validation is optional. In our flow, we use flyway migrate plugin in only jooq resources generation flow
tasks.flywayMigrate.configure {
    val taskNames = project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames
    if ("flyMigrate" in taskNames && "generateJooq" !in taskNames) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Flyway migrate is only available for generateJooq task")
    }
}

tasks.named("generateJooq").configure {
    dependsOn(tasks.named("flywayMigrate"))
    doLast {
        containerInstance?.stop()
    }
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Testcontainers spin up additional container that won't stop when you stop db container. Also, you probably want to stop regardless if task succeeds or fail. So, for the second issue the solution is to add BuildListener:

```kotlin
project.gradle.addBuildListener(object : BuildAdapter() {
    override fun buildFinished(result: BuildResult) {
        dbContainer?.stop()
    }
})
```

With second container I've just switched from testcontainers for [docker-java](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java)

```kotlin
startMigrationDBTask.doFirst {
    val dockerConf = DefaultDockerClientConfig.createDefaultConfigBuilder().build()
    dockerClient = DockerClientImpl.getInstance(
                dockerConf,
                ZerodepDockerHttpClient.Builder()
                    .dockerHost(dockerConf.dockerHost)
                    .sslConfig(dockerConf.sslConfig)
                    .build()
            )

    if (dockerClient!!.listImagesCmd().withImageNameFilter("postgres").exec().isEmpty()) {
                    dockerClient!!.pullImageCmd("postgres:latest").exec(PullImageResultCallback()).awaitCompletion()
    }
    val containerResponse = dockerClient!!.createContainerCmd("postgres")
                .withEnv("POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password", "POSTGRES_USER=postgres", "POSTGRES_DB=transactions")
                .withHostConfig(HostConfig.newHostConfig().withPortBindings(PortBinding.parse("5432:5432")))
                .exec()
    dbContainerId = containerResponse.id
    dockerClient!!.startContainerCmd(containerResponse.id).exec()
}
```

and BuildListenr will change to:

```
project.gradle.addBuildListener(object : BuildAdapter() {
    override fun buildFinished(result: BuildResult) {
        dbContainerId?.let { id ->
            dockerClient?.removeContainerCmd(id)?.withForce(true)?.exec()
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently faced a similar issue and not being able to find a sufficiently good solution for that, written a [blogpost](https://sergeylappo.github.io/posts/gradle-jooq-flyway-testcontainers/).
In short, the idea is to:

1. Add the required dependencies.
2. Create a Gradle build service, which would supply you with a database using `testcontainers`. It would also ensure that the testontainers would be stopped correctly
3. Configure Flyway with the connection info from testcontainers.
4. Do the same for jOOQ.

So here's the most important pieces of code:

```or-tag-here
{
    buildscript {
        // ...
        dependencies {
            //      Required dependencies to start testcontainers and do the migration during the build.
            classpath 'org.testcontainers:postgresql:1.19.3'
            classpath 'org.flywaydb:flyway-database-postgresql:10.4.0'
        }
    }

    plugins {
        // ...
        //  Gradle plugins for jOOQ and Flyway.
        id 'org.flywaydb.flyway' version '10.4.0'
        id 'org.jooq.jooq-codegen-gradle' version '3.19.1'
    }
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        //  Dependencies required for the application to use jooq and flyway in runtime.
        implementation "org.flywaydb:flyway-database-postgresql:$flyway_version"
        implementation "org.jooq:jooq:$jooq_version"

        //  Your database driver
        runtimeOnly "org.postgresql:postgresql:$postgres_version"
        //  Database driver for the build time.
        jooqCodegen "org.postgresql:postgresql:$postgres_version"

        //  Testcontainer dependencies for the test tasks.
        testImplementation "org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:$testcontainers_version"
        testImplementation "org.testcontainers:postgresql:$testcontainers_version"
    }

    // Here we register service for providing our database during the build.
    Provider<PostgresService> dbContainerProvider = project.getGradle()
            .getSharedServices()
            .registerIfAbsent("postgres", PostgresService.class, {})

    // ...
    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()

        //  This is only necessary if you want to reuse container for the tests.
        usesService dbContainerProvider
        doFirst {
            def dbContainer = dbContainerProvider.get().container
            systemProperty('spring.datasource.url', dbContainer.jdbcUrl)
            systemProperty('spring.datasource.username', dbContainer.username)
            systemProperty('spring.datasource.password', dbContainer.password)
        }
    }

    flywayMigrate {
        //  We need access to our database during the build.
        usesService dbContainerProvider
        //  Define location of the migrations.
        locations = ["filesystem:src/main/resources/db/migration"]
        //  Flyway plugin won't define input files for us, so to follow Gradle convention define them.
        inputs.files(fileTree("src/main/resources/db/migration"))

        doFirst {
            def dbContainer = dbContainerProvider.get().container
            //      Set up the flyway config.
            url = dbContainer.jdbcUrl
            user = dbContainer.username
            password = dbContainer.password
        }
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        //  For jOOQ to run we always need for flyway to be completed before.
        jooqCodegen.dependsOn flywayMigrate
        jooqCodegen {
            doFirst {
                def dbContainer = dbContainerProvider.get().container
                jooq {
                    configuration {
                        jdbc {
                            driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
                            url = dbContainer.jdbcUrl
                            user = dbContainer.username
                            password = dbContainer.password
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    jooq {
        //  jOOQ generation config
        configuration {
            logging = org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Logging.WARN
            generator {
                name = "org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGenerator"
                database {
                    name = "org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase"
                    includes = ".*"
                    excludes = 'flyway_schema_history'
                    inputSchema = 'public'
                }
                target {
                    packageName = 'com.testcontainers.demo.jooq'
                    directory = 'target/generated-sources/jooq'
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Build service for providing database container.
     */
    abstract class PostgresService implements BuildService<BuildServiceParameters.None>, AutoCloseable {
        private final PostgreSQLContainer container;

        PostgresService() {
            //        Services are initialized lazily, on first request to them, so we start container immediately.
            container = new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:16-alpine")
            container.start()
        }

        @Override
        void close() {
            //        Ensure to stop container in the end
            container.stop()
        }

        PostgreSQLContainer getContainer() {
            return container
        }
    }
}
```

You can see full implementation on [GitHub](https://github.com/sergeylappo/tc-guide-working-with-jooq-flyway-using-testcontainers-gradle/blob/4a92824088d46d0486098c985be7c26e8bc3629b/build.gradle)